# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: неверное имя/номер переменной

Tags: python-3.x, oracle

Здравствуйте!
Совсем недавно стал осваивать Oracle, в связи с этим вопрос. Есть код на Python:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.Connection("scott", "tiger", "ora_6215_6")

day = datetime.date(2017, 7, 18).strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
users = 'АДМИНИСТРАТОР'

cur_new = conn.cursor()
#cur_new.setinputsizes(cx_Oracle.Date(day))

sql = "SELECT FAM, DPS, VHN, VHD, USERS.FAM, OVD, DOP, TERRITOR.STR FROM ADMEXP.STOROG INNER JOIN USERS ON STOROG.USR = USERS.ID INNER JOIN TERRITOR ON STOROG.REG = TERRITOR.KOD WHERE NOT USERS.FAM = :user AND STOROG.DPS = :to_date(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY') ORDER BY STOROG.DPS DESC"

cur_new.execute(sql, {'user':users, 'date':day})

res = cur_new.fetchall()
print(res)

cur_new.close()
conn.close()
```

Постоянно ругается на

```
cur_new.execute(sql, {'user':users, 'date':day})
```

Ошибка в заголовке, спрашивал у гугла, в голове каша, помогите

Comment: а что такое `:to_date("date", "DD.MM.YYYY")` может вы имели ввиду `to_date(:date, 'DD.MM.YYYY')` ? обратите внимание, что кавычки в которых значения должны быть одинарными

Comment: Сделал так как Вы подсказали, не изменилось ничего.

Comment: это странно, ошибка возникает если в execute передается не точно такое же имя параметра как указан в запросе. в параметрах у вас user и date, значит в запросе должны быть `:user` и `:date`. попробуйте сначала запрос без параметров, прямо в запрос константы положите, потом по одному меняйте константы на параметры и добавляйте их в execute, что бы понять на чем оно ломается

Comment: Я делал уже так, все выполняется без ошибок, но возвращается пустой список, что странно, ибо запускал в SQL Plus запрос выполнялся и возвращал данные. Запрос выглядит так: `sql = "SELECT STOROG.FAM, STOROG.DPS, STOROG.VHN, STOROG.VHD, USERS.FAM, STOROG.OVD, STOROG.DOP, TERRITOR.STR FROM ADMEXP.STOROG INNER JOIN USERS ON STOROG.USR = USERS.ID INNER JOIN TERRITOR ON STOROG.REG = TERRITOR.KOD WHERE NOT USERS.FAM = 'АДМИНИСТРАТОР' AND STOROG.DPS = '18.07.2017' ORDER BY STOROG.DPS DESC"` Кусок кода где возникала ошибка выглядит так:`cur_new.execute(sql)`

Comment: А вас STOROG.DPS имеет тип данных строка и там дата лежит действительно в виде DD.MM.YYYY. Если это не так то выполнение этого запроса зависит от настроек формата даты в клиенте. Поэтому используйте условие с явным переводом строки в дату из нужного формата: `STOROG.DPS = TO_DATE('18.07.2017','DD.MM.YYYY')`

Comment: К сожалению вернул пустую строку. Полностью убрал тот кусок кода который вы привели в качестве примера, данные появились в виде списка. Не знаю поможет ли это, но дата хранится в базе вот в таком формате `12.10.2016 0:00:00`

Comment: А тип поля какой `date` или char/varchar какой нибудь ?

Comment: тип поля `date`

Comment: тогда TO_DATE('18.07.2017','DD.MM.YYYY') просто обязан находить записи, если за эту дату они есть

Comment: вы правы за 18.07.2017 записей в базе не оказалось. Если сделать запрос таким `SELECT STOROG.FAM, STOROG.DPS, STOROG.VHN, STOROG.VHD, USERS.FAM, STOROG.OVD, STOROG.DOP, TERRITOR.STR FROM ADMEXP.STOROG INNER JOIN USERS ON STOROG.USR = USERS.ID INNER JOIN TERRITOR ON STOROG.REG = TERRITOR.KOD WHERE NOT USERS.FAM = 'АДМИНИСТРАТОР' AND STOROG.DPS >= '18.07.2017' ORDER BY STOROG.DPS DESC` данные появляются.

Comment: Но когда делаем так: `SELECT STOROG.FAM, STOROG.DPS, STOROG.VHN, STOROG.VHD, USERS.FAM, STOROG.OVD, STOROG.DOP, TERRITOR.STR FROM ADMEXP.STOROG INNER JOIN USERS ON STOROG.USR = USERS.ID INNER JOIN TERRITOR ON STOROG.REG = TERRITOR.KOD WHERE NOT USERS.FAM = :user AND STOROG.DPS >= :date ORDER BY STOROG.DPS DESC"` появляется ошибка как в заголовке. Дату делаем строкой.

Comment: Если не сложно подскажите, пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы результат запроса возвращался словарем где ключ название поля базы, а значение результат запроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось проблема была с переменными, стоило изменить их название все заработало итоговый код такой:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.Connection("scott", "tiger", "ora_6215_6")

date2 = '18.07.2017'
users = 'АДМИНИСТРАТОР'

cur_new = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT FAM, DPS, VHN, VHD, USERS.FAM, OVD, DOP, TERRITOR.STR 
FROM ADMEXP.STOROG INNER JOIN USERS ON STOROG.USR = USERS.ID INNER JOIN TERRITOR ON STOROG.REG = TERRITOR.KOD 
WHERE NOT USERS.FAM = :user1 AND STOROG.DPS = :date1 ORDER BY STOROG.DPS DESC"

cur_new.execute(sql, {'user1':users2, 'date1':date2})

for res in cur:
    print(res)

cur_new.close()
conn.close()
```

Также получилось сделать так чтобы результат запроса возвращался словарем, где ключ название поля базы, а значение результат запроса:

```
def makeDictFactory(cursor):
columnNames = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]
def createRow(*args):
    return dict(zip(columnNames, args))
return createRow
```